# How to change a specific part of the state with a timeout in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, return, timeout, blur

Here is my state:

```
const birthdayAnimState = {
    visible: 1,
    blurVisible: 1,
};

const [state, setState] = useState(birthdayAnimState);
const { visible, blurVisible } = state;
```

When my blur is pressed I call this method:

```
const onBlurPress = () => {
    setState({
        visible: 0,
        blurVisible,
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        setState({
            visible,
            blurVisible: 0,
        });
    }, 1000);
};
```

And here is what I'm returning:

```
blurVisible
    ?
        <AnimatedBlurView>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onBlurPress}>
                 {...}
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </AnimatedBlurView>
    : null
```

So the onBlurPress method looks kinda dirty and I was wondering if I can implement changing a specific part of state with a timeout without duplicating it. Any ideas about how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can spread the original state and update the value of your choice and update the state:

```js
const onBlurPress = () => {
    setState({
        ...state,
        visible: 0,
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        setState({
            ...state,
            blurVisible: 0,
        });
    }, 1000);
};
``
```

Comment: It is working, but I don't think that you need to spread the state, as it is a simple object, isn't it ?

Comment: it's not advisable to mutate the state directly so usually spread operator is used to create a new copy of that and then update the state.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really understood, but in order to modify a specific part of the state, you can simply do this:

```
 setState({
    visible: 0
});
```

Or this :

```
 setState({
    blurVisible : 0
});
```

It is working because the setState is doing a shallow merge. If you have more complex objects, you can do a deep merge by spreading the state. Have a look here :
https://medium.com/@imrobinkim/how-state-updates-are-merged-in-react-e07fc669fec2

Answer (score 0):

what's your goal with this? what are you trying to do ?